# Xcode error "Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration"

Tags: swift, firebase, google-signin

Getting a error at `func filepriavte; func setupGoogleButtons()` saying

> Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration

```
import UIKit

import Firebase

import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupGoogleButtons()
    }
    
    ****func filepriavte; func setupGoogleButtons()** {**
        // Add Google Login Button
        
        let googleButton = GIDSignInButton()
        googleButton.frame = CGReact(x: 60, y: 500, width: view.frame.width - 115,
                                     geight: 50)
        view.addSubview(googleButton)
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: `****func filepriavte; func setupGoogleButtons()** {**` should be `fileprivate func setupGoogleButtons()`

Comment: What's the deal with all of the asterisks?

Answer (score 0):

The overall Controller should look like this

```
import UIKit

import Firebase

import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupGoogleButtons()
    }

    priavte func setupGoogleButtons() { // Use private instead of fileprivate
        // Add Google Login Button

        let googleButton = GIDSignInButton()
        googleButton.frame = CGReact(x: 60, y: 500, width: view.frame.width - 115,
                                     geight: 50)
        view.addSubview(googleButton)

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Hope this will work.